# TYPO3: Extend an existing CType with a new identifier

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I want to add a new CType in TYPO3. I think I have read that it is possible to create a new CType based on an existing one.

But I can't find that again, but that is precisely what I want. I want a different functionality for the Textpic at a specific spot.

I think the cleanest way would be to extend from the Textpic with another identifier. So I have two render options. At the moment, I don't need any further information from the backend user, but that can change.

I hope you can help me with that.

Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello my solutions looks pretty stand like describe in the docs:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#configurece-extend-tt-content

The only thing I did a bit notable was this line:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['extkey_identifier'] = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['textpic'];
```

So it will always catch up on updates with the original element.
Also, it makes sense that you have to define the other values.